# Captcha Not Display Any Image

Tags: php, yii, captcha

After i used multiple layouts in my app , then Cpatcha not display any image :(

This my code

Controller :

```
public function actions()
        {
                return array(
                        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
                        'captcha'=>array(
                                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
                        ),
                        // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
                        // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
                        'page'=>array(
                                'class'=>'CViewAction',
                        ),
                );
        }
```

model :

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
                array('email, password', 'required','message'=>'-- {attribute}  '),

                array('password', 'authenticate'),

                // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'message'=>' {attribute}  Error '),

);

}
```

view call widget

```
...
        <div>
                <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
                </div>
...
```

I tested it on request recorder and it sent and received requests .
[image: Captcha]

Thanks in advance

Comment: since you are sure about captcha not showing only after addition of multiple layouts, add the code for multiple layouts, maybe there was some mistake there which lead to this, although it's unlikely. and did you check your css?

Comment: I guess now multiple style not related to this problem ?!! 
I guess something else

Comment: ok do test that to be sure, try with multiple layout, and without. see if it fails for both. also can you show your entire captcha row from the view, are you doing the checkRequirements check?

Comment: please check my question and answers in yii forum
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/38932-captcha-not-disply-any-image/

Comment: hmm, so it seems that there might be some white space somewhere, check the files that you copy pasted, definitely some error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it  by add Remove Bom Function

```
ob_start('My_OB');
function My_OB($str, $flags)
{
    //remove UTF-8 BOM
    $str = preg_replace("/\xef\xbb\xbf/","",$str);

    return $str;
}
```

I guess the problem was in page encoding .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using access control, it is most likely that you are not setting `accessRules` for the captcha action. You need to add the action, something like:

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow', // all users
            'actions' => ("captcha"),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // authenticated users
            'actions' => ("captcha"),
            'users' => array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny', // deny all users
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```